# Stopping running code

Tags: python, spyder

I'd like to stop code while running in Spyder, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>/ <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> nor <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>/ <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> does not work for me, even the blue stop button (normally used for debug).

I work under Yosemite 10.10.3 and am using Spyder 2.3.4 and Python 2.7
Has someone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

The consoles both python and ipython, when executing code have a stop button in the top right corner of the panes.

The debug button has no business with that as you rightly said it is for debugging, so unless you are debugging you should not expect it to stop a non debugging session.

Comment: @Khalife, if `Ctrl+C` or `Cmd+C` are not working, that's an Spyder bug. Please consider opening an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) in case this is still a problem for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Click 3 lines in console (Options button) and click restart kernel.